# PHP day and month comparison

Tags: php, date

I am trying to do the following: use the session variables `$date_from` and `$date_to` that mark and compare them with these date intervals. This is what I have so far:

This is the format that I am using, only days and months:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('28-04-2014');

$seasonStart = date_format($date1, 'd-m');
```

Take for example todays date, `28-03-2014`, and do the same thing, store it in a variable and the condition in the if loop would be

```
if (28-03 < 28-04)
echo "it works"
```

However this doesn't work. I have noticed that it only compares the dates but not the months 
if i change `28-03 to 01-08` it would work which is obviously not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing strings (and in your second example integers), not dates. That's why you see the results you are seeing. Fortunately comparing dates is easy in PHP as DateTime objects are comparible. No formatting needs to be done beforehand.

```
$date1 = new DateTime('28-04-2014');
$date2 = new DateTime();
if ($date1 > $date2) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: This would be the simplest solution, and I have tried this as well, however the "year" part in the datetime is a bit of a problem. Do you know if there a way to keep the DateTime function but without the year part?

Comment: How is the year part problematic? We might be able to work around it.

Comment: Well what would happen if someone makes a reservation this same day but next year
$date2 would be 28-04-2015 which is larger than $date1 and the condition doesn't work.

Comment: Date comparisons are not done as strings. PHP compares them as dates. Don't think of how the date looks as a string. That is misleading.

Comment: Here is the problem. Same code as yours above, just different year:
$date1 = new DateTime('27-04-2013');
  $date2 = new DateTime();
  if ($date1 > $date2) {
    echo "works"; 
  }
  else{
    echo "fail"; 
  } 
It echoes fail, because of the year. This example #2 is something that could be useful if these parameters could be modified.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use unix time with the `strtotime` function.

```
$time1 = strtotime("28 March 2014");
$time2 = strtotime("28 February 2014");
if($time1 > $time2){ //stuff }
```

I'm not sure if this would be the most successful way, but I'd probably do it this way myself.